# 2 different Model share 1 unique Photo Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, photo

Hello Rails Community !

I don't know how to structure my different models.

I have 2 differents models : **cars** and **house**
Theses models can have multiple photos.

My questions are :

- Is it possible to use 1 photo model for the cars and house or I need to create 1 cars_photos model and 1 house_photos model
- If it's possible, how can I generate my Photo model ?

**=> Option 1**

```
rails g model Photo name:string, description:text car:references house:references
```

**Car.rb**

```
has_many :photos
```

**House.rb**

```
has_many :photos
```

**Photo.rb**

```
belongs_to :car
belongs_to :house
```

The problem with this option is that a photo will have to be linked with a car AND with a house. Witch is not good.
=> I want a photo be linked with a car OR with a house

I don't know how to proceed...

Thx !

Comment: Please see [the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) on the has_many :through Association.

Comment: You can use a polymorphic association. The official Rails' guide use the image relation as example, which fits perfectly your requirements : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost the exact prototypical `polymorphic` association from the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

```
$ rails g model Photo name:string description:text imageable:references{polymorphic}:index
```

Produces this migration file

```
class CreatePhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :photos do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.references :imageable, polymorphic: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

`t.references :imageable, polymorphic: true` is going to give you two columns on your `photos` table: `imageable_id:integer` which will be the `id` column of the associated object, and `imageable_type:string` which will be the stringified class name of the associated object. This allows `photos` to interface with and belong to any model on one association.

Then your models should look like this

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :photos, as: :imageable
end

class House < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :photos, as: :imageable
end
```

You can add a `Photo` to a `Car` with `Car.find(params[:car_id]).photos.create` and assign a `Car` to a `Photo` with `Photo.new imageable: Car.find(params[:car_id])`

Comment: Hello m.simon borg
Thx for your answer
I test your solution tomorrow :)

Comment: Hello m.simon borg. It's working perfectly ! Many Thx from Paris, France ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can reuse photos for both cars and house.

There are two major gems
for photo uploading: [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave).

Have a look at them before you continue with your modeling!